# Model inheritance in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

**Groundwork**

I have a database design (snipped to relevant portions) like so:

```
records
  entities
    people
```

where no proper relationship exists between the tables, but rather `records` is extended by `entities` is extended by `people` by sharing the same `id`.

I have my Eloquent models similarly defined so that `Record` is extended by `Entity` is extended by `Person`.

**Goal**

`Record` and `Entity` are abstract and I want to simply use `Person` and other models at that level in the hierarchy.

**Problem**

How do I 'link' `Record` and `Entity` to `Person` to make this all work seamlessly? I don't think relationships is appropriate. I assume it's related to something like this:

```
protected __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you still create a model for Person, Entity, and Record, and link them together with "belongsTo" relationships. (add entity_id column to "People" table, add "record_id" to "Entities" table).

If you are only working with the Person model, you could add a "saved" model observer to create the entity and record entries whenever you create a Person, and tie them all together with a global id.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-observers

If you did it this way, you could access the person's entity and record field by doing something like:

$person->entity->fieldName

$person->record->fieldName

All that being said, this seems way too complicated.  I would only have one table for People and store all the person's data there.  imo.

Comment: You're right. This process doesn't feel as natural as I would like. I think I'll flatten the table structure. :) Thanks!